# Migrating to a newer BloC version problem

Tags: flutter, migration, bloc, state-management, flutter-bloc

I'm trying to learn about the BloC pattern, I first meet this patter in the following git repository [fitness](https://github.com/perpetio/fitness), I tried using my own code but it had many errors and problems, so I figured I'd better try 1 to 1 their code first and then Ill see changes, so I tried it but their code also results in errors.

I solved some of them, but the BloC related one are still there, you can refer to this issue I opened for them [PageSwipe/Change Issue](https://github.com/perpetio/fitness/issues/23) where I explain the errors and where they originated from in the code.

I've tried to follow the migration guide located here [migration guide](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/migration), but with no luck so far.

The BloC code can be found here [first page BloC code](https://github.com/perpetio/fitness/tree/master/lib/screens/onboarding/bloc)

if there is anything else related that needed in order to solve this
problem, comment it and I'll add it

Error:

```
Bad state: add(PageSwipedEvent) was called without a registered event handler.
Make sure to register a handler via on<PageSwipedEvent>((event, emit) {...})
```

Line in code that result in that error:

```
bloc.add(PageChangedEvent());
// or
bloc.add(PageSwipedEvent(index: index));
```

BloC code:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

part 'onboarding_event.dart';
part 'onboarding_state.dart';

class OnboardingBloc extends Bloc<OnboardingEvent, OnboardingState> {
  OnboardingBloc() : super(OnboardingInitial());

  int pageIndex = 0;

  final pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);

  @override
  Stream<OnboardingState> mapEventToState(
    OnboardingEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is PageChangedEvent) {
      if (pageIndex == 2) {
        yield NextScreenState();
        return;
      }
      pageIndex += 1;

      pageController.animateToPage(
        pageIndex,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        curve: Curves.ease,
      );

      yield PageChangedState(counter: pageIndex);
    } else if (event is PageSwipedEvent) {
      pageIndex = event.index;
      yield PageChangedState(counter: pageIndex);
    }
  }
}
```

I tried adding this also:

```
on<PageSwipedEvent>((event, emit) => mapEventToState(event));
```

but it doesnt seem to work (it doesn't show the problem anymore, but it does not get the job done either.

#### Edit:

Flutter version:

[image: Flutter version]

Comment: Add the problem description and relevant code to the question. If the links later become invalid, the question here on SO should remain understandable. The links can be kept for reference. And of course, it should be a minimal reproducible example. Not just, "here is all my code"

Comment: For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Which Flutter version are you using ? I just cloned the Fitness repository, compiled and ran it with Flutter 2.2.2 and everything is alright

Comment: Added in question screenshot of it @FDuhen

Comment: What version of Bloc are you using?

Comment: Im not sure, but I think above 8.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with `on<PageSwipedEvent>((event, emit) => mapEventToState(event));`. The problem is that you are mixing several different versions of BLoC in one piece of code. The `mapEventToState()` method uses `yield` instead of `on<Event>((event, emit) => emit(State))`. This was changed in BLoC 8.0.0. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc/changelog. Since you said that adding `on<PageChangedEvent>((event, emit) => mapEventToState(event));` fixed the error even though the code still doesn't produce a result, I think you are using version 8.0.0 or higher.

Try switching the `yield` to `on<Event>((event, emit) => emit(State))` and moving the on handlers inside the constructor:

```
class OnboardingBloc extends Bloc<OnboardingEvent, OnboardingState> {

  int pageIndex = 0;
  final pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);

  OnboardingBloc() : super(OnboardingInitial()){

    on<PageChangedEvent>((event, emit) async {
    
        if (pageIndex == 2) {
            emit(NextScreenState());
            return;
          }
          pageIndex += 1;
        
          pageController.animateToPage(
            pageIndex,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            curve: Curves.ease,
          );
        emit(PageChangedState(counter: pageIndex));
    
    });

    on<PageSwipedEvent>((event, emit) async {
       pageIndex = event.index;
       emit(PageChangedState(counter: pageIndex));
    });

}
```